# Python code reading only even number of lines

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a python code that will read a (text) file that contains information about the proton number, symbol, and name of the value. (e.g. 1,H,Hydrogen) The user will enter any of the detail and the program will show all information. The problem occurs that the program only reads an even number of lines. What is the error in this code. Please justify with reasons. Thanks.

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
inf = open(fname,"r")

num = []
syb = []
name = []

for line in inf:
    line = inf.readline().strip()
    line = list(line.split(","))
    num.append(line[0])
    syb.append(line[1])
    name.append(line[2])


inf.close()

userinput = input("Enter your input: ").capitalize()
while userinput !="":
    type(userinput)
    if userinput in num:
        pos = num.index(userinput)
        print("Proton number:",num[pos],"Symbol: ",syb[pos],"Name: ",name[pos])

    elif userinput in syb:
        pos = syb.index(userinput)
        print("Proton number:",num[pos],"Symbol: ",syb[pos],"Name: ",name[pos])

    elif userinput in name:
        pos = name.index(userinput)
        print("Proton number:",num[pos],"Symbol: ",syb[pos],"Name: ",name[pos])

    else:
        print("Error! Invalid input.")
    userinput = input("Enter your input: ").capitalize()
```

Comment: Can you post sample data of your text file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need is to get a string with all of the file, like so:

```
inf = open(fname,"r") # The r here isn't needed, Python assumes it's reading unless you specify w, but it's good practice anyway.
txt = inf.read() # Get everything in the file, and put it in txt.
inf.close() # Depending on OS, this is needed so that Python doesn't hog the file, and other programs can use it when Python is done.
```

I see this code here:

```
for line in inf:
    line = inf.readline().strip()
```

And here's what is going on:
`inf` is an object pointing to the file, not the text in the file, so whatever it's doing is going to not be what you want. If you want to keep using the file object, you need this:

```
while True:
    try:
        line = inf.readline().strip()
    except EOFError: # If the end of the file is reached, or the line is empty, break from the loop. If you expect empty lines in the file, change the second break to a continue to ignore them.
        break
    if not line:
        break
```

There is a simpler way too, and it's this:

```
for line in txt.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        continue # Ignore empty lines, as these will be annoying later on.
    # now you can use it.
```

Comment: Although there are simpler to do it, it's not wrong to iterate over the file object as it will yield the file's contents line by line.

Comment: The way you do it though, wouldn't that result in every second line being processed?

Comment: I don't think so since I don't call any sort of `read` inside the loop. I haven't tested my code though

Answer (score 4):

`for line in inf` is already iterating over each line, so there is no need to `readline` afterwards. If you do, it will move the pointer forward by one additional step, so you discard the first line, read the second, discard the third etc.

Working loop:

```
for line in inf:
    line = inf.strip()
    line = list(line.split(","))
    num.append(line[0])
    syb.append(line[1])
    name.append(line[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are reading two lines with every iteration:

```py
for line in inf:
    line = inf.readline().strip()
```

One by iterating over your file, and another one explicitly by calling `readline()`. You'd probably only need your reading loop like this (notice the moved strip):

```py
for line in inf:
    line = list(line.strip().split(","))
    num.append(line[0])
    syb.append(line[1])
    name.append(line[2])
```

However, you can also use `readlines()` to get an list of lines from your file with the trailing newline characters already removed. Lastly, I recommend using a context manager for opening your file, resulting in:

```py
num = []
syb = []
name = []
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
with open(fname,"r") as inf:
    for line in inf.readlines():
        line = list(line.split(","))
        num.append(line[0])
        syb.append(line[1])
        name.append(line[2])

userinput = input("Enter your input: ").capitalize()
# ... the rest of your code here
```